# Commutative matrix question

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was doing my HW, and I am confused with one thing. To show that a matrix is commutative, do we need to show both $x+y = y+x$ and $xy=yx$? Or just by showing $xy=yx$ would suffice?

Comment: What is a *commutative* matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing $xy=yx$ suffices, $x+y=y+x$ is trivial, since addition of matrix elements is always commutative, as far as I know...

Comment: Yes, addition is commutative, and that's why I was thinking whether it's necessary to show or not.

Comment: I would say, it's not necessary. According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices): *In linear algebra, two matrices $A$ and $B$ are said to commute if $AB=BA$...*

Comment: @abcd1234 your welcome (to MSE ;-)...